# Receiving "kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9841" error from Paw

Tags: paw-app

I'm attempting to make a request using [Paw](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/), and I'm getting this mysterious error:

kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL error -9841

Attempts to execute the same request using cURL, other OS X REST clients, etc... all work with no problem at all. I've search for references to the `-9841` instance of this error, and have turned up nothing.

Comment: According to Apple's doc, it is: "peer cert is valid, or was ignored if verification disabled". I recommend you switch to another HTTP library Paw supports, in the Preferences (Paw menu > Preferences), tab "HTTP" choose another HTTP Library (either ASIHTTPRequest or NSURLConnection).

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by [Micha Mazaheri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698645/micha-mazaheri), in a previous comment, the best way to solve this problem is to go to Paw preferences and to choose a different client library from within the HTTP tab. I was not aware this was an option.

Comment: I had this same issue when I was using Paw with Chalres Proxy to allow my traffic to go external. Once I enabled SSL proxying for the request everything worked fine. See Micha comment for the location to set your proxy.